# Web-scraping with Selenium in Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, pycharm

I am trying to get the latest price from a currency rate on Bloomberg using Python + Selenium + PhantomJS

Here is the [URL](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDBRL:CUR)

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="overviewRow__0956421f">
    <span class="priceText__1853e8a5">3.9100</span>
    <span class="currency__defc7184">BRL</span>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
my_url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDBRL:CUR'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(my_url)
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("priceText__1853e8a5")
print(price)
```

But is not scraping.

Here is the error stack trace:

```
/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/bin/python /Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/wiki.py
/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/wiki.py", line 8, in <module>
    price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("overviewRow__0956421f")
  File "/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 563, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/marcelo/PycharmProjects/extractwiki/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'overviewRow__0956421f'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"110","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:54302","User-Agent":"selenium/3.14.0 (python mac)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"value\": \"overviewRow__0956421f\", \"sessionId\": \"1eaf82f0-a39a-11e8-867d-9dbde70c7bc5\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/1eaf82f0-a39a-11e8-867d-9dbde70c7bc5/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could some expert help me please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PhantomJS is deprecated and may not work anymore

Comment: IMHO Selenium is not proper tool for this task. There is a [Bloombergs API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/bloomberg) which you can use in [Python](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/#download-38165)

Comment: @Andersson Oh, nice. I will check.

Comment: That URL appears to return empty responses in *some* cases, for example with `curl 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDBRL:CUR'`. It works fine from the browser. Try to see if the driver got anything.

Comment: The terms of service say no scraping. The API seems the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
my_url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDBRL:CUR'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(my_url)
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("priceText__1853e8a5")
for value in price:print(value.text)
```